# Apollo Android (GraphQL) custom type build file warning: "Cannot assign value to final field"

Tags: android, apollo

The following closure in the app-level build file shows the warning "Cannot assign value to final field" in relation to the customTypeMapping object:

```
apollo {
    customTypeMapping = [
        "DateTime" : "java.lang.String",
        "UUID" : "java.lang.String",
        "JSONString" : "java.lang.String"
    ]
}
```

This appears to be a recent change in a dependency or tools. I've tried other statement formats, e.g.:

```
    customTypeMapping["DateTime"]="java.lang.String"
```

but without success (that shows a build error: No such property: DateTime for class: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState)

The code at the start of this question functions as expected, but how do I clear the warning?

Apollo dependency:

```
classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is correct, but you also need to finish it by registering your custom adapter.

some extra detail may be that your reference (apollo) must be in the end of the gradle file (after all your other dependencies have been declared)

In my case I have a special case with the UUID type, what I did was:

At the end of my app build.gradle

```
apollo {
    customTypeMapping = [
            "UUID" : "java.lang.String"
    ]
}
```

Inside of the class I'm using Apollo:

created my Custom Adapter

```
   CustomTypeAdapter<String> customTypeAdapter = new CustomTypeAdapter<String>() {
        @Override
        public String decode(@NotNull CustomTypeValue value) {
            return value.toString();
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public CustomTypeValue encode(@NotNull String value) {
            return new CustomTypeValue.GraphQLString(value);
        }
    };
```

And then when initialising Apollo

```
        apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder().addCustomTypeAdapter(CustomType.UUID, customTypeAdapter)
            .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
            .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

Refer to the framework if you have more questions, it can be a little complicated, but I think with this example you can get trough it.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#custom-scalar-types